Trouble Installing FBprophet
Below is the code when I try to install pystan, I already have Numpy and Cython installed, but the pystan installation gives this error. My goal is to install FBprophet, and I figured this step needs to work before I can install it since it also gives errors when I try pip install fbprophet. Could anyone take a look at this?
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      /private/var/folders/d7/r1wlkvcs4sn7fk8q5nc6rr640000gn/T/pip-req-build-finxexd0/setup.py:61: DeprecationWarning: Attribute s is deprecated and will be removed in Python 3.14; use value instead
        self.version = node.value.s
      Cython>=0.22 and NumPy are required.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pystan
  Running setup.py clean for pystan
Failed to build pystan
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pystan)
(.venv)  % pip install cython
Requirement already satisfied: cython in ./.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages (3.0.10)
(.venv)  Projects % pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages (1.26.4)
(.venv) Projects % `

Installing Cython should've made it possible to install pystan.

According to the docs, you will need a C++ compiler such as gcc ≥9.0 or clang ≥10.0 to install PyStan.
Then run python3 -m pip install pystan. Note that PyStan runs on Linux and macOS.

Getting the same error after installing brew and gcc

What version of gcc?

It's version 15.0.0. I'm having trouble building editables for prophet

I saw that prophet supports up to python 3.11. You seem to be using 3.12. Have you tried using Python 3.11? Also did you fix the original error with pystan?

In your post on Discord, you provided a screenshot that said,
git install git+https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan2.git@master

I believe that is what's causing the error. This is because pystan2 was dead officially in 2021,,

This repository has been archived by the owner on Mar 19, 2021. It is now read-only.

Moreover, from the tox.ini you can see Pystan2 only supports Python 3.4-3.6
envlist = py36,py35,py34

You need to install pystan3, you can find those instructions here, or if that fails or you must install from github you can target the official pystan3 repo at https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan.
